# iOS Library for signing request with OAuth1?

Tags: ios, oauth

Can someone recommend an iOS library for signing OAuth1 requests.  I have looked at AFOAuth1Client but it's not clear how to sign a request where the authorization token has been generated after the user has authenticated using their user id and pw.  It appears AFOAuth1Client assumes that the token was received via an OAuth get token request.

Answer (score 1):

Digging in to AFOAuth1Client I performed the following:

```
AFOAuth1Client *httpClient = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:url key:consumerKey secret:consumerSecret];
AFOAuth1Token *token = [[AFOAuth1Token alloc] initWithKey:accessToken secret:tokenSecret session:nil expiration:nil renewable:YES];
httpClient.accessToken = token;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are around 167 listed on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=oauth%20&ref=cmdform&type=Repositories) (though some are forks and not all support OAuth 1). I'd be remiss if I didn't mention my own... [SDOAuthHelper](https://github.com/sdarlington/SDOAuthHelper/blob/master/SDOAuthHelper.h).

OAuth is not straight-forward. I would suggest you stick with AFOAuth1Client and try to make it work. They all go through the same process and understanding it will help when you (invariably) get errors with the signature.